# selecting daily revised hourly values for a month

Tags: postgresql, birt

I have two queries
first one return latest Revision number for each date for a month

```
select  max(a.wdcm_revision_no)
from wb_declared_capacity_master a, wb_declared_capacity_det_unit b
where a.wdcm_internal_id = b.wdcd_ref_id and b.wdcm_unit = 'HSY_Unit1' and to_char(a.wdcm_date,'MM YYYY')='08 2019' group by a.wdcm_date
```

And second query which returns all the data irrespective of any revision

```
select a1.wdcm_date, b1.wdcd_block_no, c1.wdcd_capacity, c1.wdcd_approval, a1.wdcm_revision_no
from wb_declared_capacity_master a1, wb_declared_capacity_det_unit b1, wb_declared_capacity_detail c1
where a1.wdcm_internal_id = b1.wdcd_ref_id and a1.wdcm_internal_id = c1.wdcd_ref_id and b1.wdcm_unit = 'HSY_Unit1' and to_char(a1.wdcm_date,'MM YYYY')='08 2019'and b1.wdcd_block_no = c1.wdcd_block_no
```

Now I want to pass each date's latest revision from first query in where condition of second query expecting to return all the values based on those latest revision number

Answer (score 0):

You can combine then into 1 query. The 1st becoming a CTE which is then fed into the 2nd. I believe the following is close, but as you didn't actually indicate where you wanted to "pass in the result" I'm making assumption that seems likely, but it's still an assumption.

```
with latest (revision) as
-- first query
    ( select max(a.wdcm_revision_no) 
        from wb_declared_capacity_master a
           , wb_declared_capacity_det_unit b
        where a.wdcm_internal_id = b.wdcd_ref_id 
          and b.wdcm_unit = 'HSY_Unit1' 
          and to_char(a.wdcm_date,'MM YYYY')='08 2019' 
        group by a.wdcm_date
    )
-- And second query which returns all the data irrespective of any revision
select a1.wdcm_date
     , b1.wdcd_block_no
     , c1.wdcd_capacity
     , c1.wdcd_approval
     , a1.wdcm_revision_no
  from wb_declared_capacity_master   a1
     , wb_declared_capacity_det_unit b1
     , wb_declared_capacity_detail   c1   
     , latest
 where a1.wdcm_internal_id = b1.wdcd_ref_id 
   and a1.wdcm_internal_id = c1.wdcd_ref_id 
   and b1.wdcm_unit = 'HSY_Unit1' 
   and to_char(a1.wdcm_date,'MM YYYY')='08 2019'
   and b1.wdcd_block_no = c1.wdcd_block_no 
   and a1.wdcm_revision_no = latest.revision;    ---- you didn't actually say where to "pass it in" this seems likely
```

I've kept the join format you used but you really should begin using the modern ANSI/ISO standard join format. (Modern meaning being in ONLY since 1992 or so).

Comment: yes,  you are right.. I have to pass it on latest revision into second one to get proper results. Thanks for your effort, let me check the same by copying it to server